# Разница между переменными в PHP и JS

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, права ли я. Интересует больше PHP, можно ли так делать, есть ли какие-то подводные камни.

Переменную в JS нужно объявить

```
var a = "1";
a += 1;
alert(a); // '11'
```

Так работать не будет

```
a += 1;
alert(a);
```

А в PHP всё работает

```
$a .= 1;
echo $a; // '1'
```

В JS не работает

```
var a = '1';
if (a == '0') {b = '3';}
alert(b);
```

Так покажет, что переменная не существует

```
var a = '1';
if (a == '0') {var b = '3';}
alert(b); // undefined
```

Я объявляю переменную до if

```
var a = '1',
    b = '';
if (a == '0') {b = '3';}
alert(b); // ''
```

Зато так работает

```
var a = '1';
if (a == '1') {var b = '3';}
alert(b); // '3'
```

А в PHP всё работает

```
$a = '1';
if ($a == '1') {$b = '3';}
echo $b; // '3'
```

И когда переменная не объявлена, возвращается пустое значение, а не undefined

```
$a = '1';
if ($a == '0') {$b = '3';}
if ($b == '') echo "Hellow"; // "Hellow"
```

Comment: у вас немного примеры разные.... например в js пишите `if (a == '0') {b = '3';}`  то есть сравниваете с нулем, хотя `a` объявили равной 1 ..... а в PHP `if ($a == '1') {$b = '3';}` при этом `$a = 1;` ........ но ведь в js если сравнивать с 1 то `alert` выведет 3 как и в PHP .......в первом примере с `var a = "1";`  тоже в js у вас одно написано а в PHP другое..... а ведь если написать `$a = "1";
$a .= 1;
echo $a;` тоже выведет `11` .......... или так надо?

Comment: `if ($b == '') echo "Hellow"; // "Hellow"` здесь это `undefined`, просто надо проверять === это проверяет тип

Comment: Переменные следует объявлять всегда. Простейшие грабли: если, как показано в PHP-примерах, переменные не объявлять, а код находится, скажем, в процедуре, то можно вместо неявного объявления локальной переменной грохнуть значение переменной глобальной. И программа будет тебе очень благодарна...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `php` берет на себя объявления переменных, делая это непрозрачно, невидимо для пользователя. Объявляются они в текущем контексте. Например:

```
function test(){
    $a = 'test passed';
}
test();
var_dump($a);// >>> NULL
```

---

`JS` же наоборот, требует явного определения переменных, однако, не требуя явно указывать их тип. При том, объявление переменной в любом месте кода, поднимает ее в начало текущего контекста, например:

```
function a(){
    console.log(a);
    var a = 'test';
}
//будет аналогично записи
function b(){
    var a;
    console.log(a);
    a = 'test';
}
```

Переменные в обоих языках объявляются в текущих контекстах, кроме того, `php` не ищет переменные в контексте выше(только если не используется ключевое слово `global`, которое позволяет использовать переменные из глобального контекста):

```
//php
$a = 'test';
function test(){
    var_dump($a);// >>> NULL
    $a  = 'test passed';
    echo $a;// >>> 'test passed'
}
test();
echo $a;// >>> 'test'
```

Однако, `js` "ищет" объявление переменной в контекстах, от самого вложенного, до самого общего, и если не находит, то посылает сообщение с ошибкой.

```
//js
var a = 'test';
var b = 'test N2';
function hax(){
    a = 'test passed';
    var b = 'test N2 passed';
    function c(){
        var a = 'test has been failed!';
        console.log(a, b) //>>>'test has been failed', 'test N2 passed'
    }
    c();
}
hax();
console.log(a, b);// >>> 'test passed', 'test N2'
```

Comment: Это разница в процессах объявления и доступа к переменным, а по сути переменная она что в PHP, что в C, что в Java что в других ЯП. Переменная это контейнер для хранения переменных данных программы.

Comment: Хотя я так и не поняла про угрозу для глобальной переменной. Её ведь следует обозначать global. Выходит, что в PHP глобальную переменную нужно объявлять, а локальная подцепится и из цикла и из условия

Comment: Хм, а ведь и правда. Пока что, уберу из ответа этот пункт, возможно впоследствии @Akina нам объяснит в чем же дело, мб я где-то профейлил

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы проверить переменную на существование необходимо сделать if (isset($b))